# onreceive() not working with Android O

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am testing on Android O phone. I have a Broadcast receiver registred to receive the Bluetooth status change event. I have added this inside my code as

```
context.registerReceiver(receiver , BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
```

When i test, the callback do not come to `onreceive()`. I have read that Android O do not support implicit broadcast. I am not sure why `onreceive()` is not fired. Is Bluetooth Action state change intent having issues with Android O ?

Comment: do you have correct permissions defined in manifest?

Comment: @krupal shah It is not mentioned in manifest. Has anyone tested on Android O

Answer (score 1):

ACTION_STATE_CHANGED is not in the list of [Implicit Broadcast Exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html).

Changing to the ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED, ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED, ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED and/or  ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED, that are in the list of whitelisted actions, might solve your issue.